# GenServer call inside macro

Tags: macros, elixir

I defined a macro like this:

```
defmodule Test do
  defmacro __using__ do
    quote do
      require Test
      import Test
    end
  end

  defmacro my_macro do
    quote do
      Gernserver.call() # generic server call from other module
    end
  end
end
```

I have this code inside a lib which I am building. When testing this lib in a different application I get a compile error on the file which has the `use Test`.

Error: `exited in: GenServer.call ...` `exit no process` (on the line of the my_macro call, more specifically on the genserver call). As if the genserver was not running, and it is not because it is compile time.

Adding a simple Application.ensure_all_started(:lib_name) to the **using** macro seems to fix the problem. But then again, at compile time the code shouldn't be running, am I right ? Or is here something I am not seeing ? Maybe I can not use genserver calls on a macro ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're calling this macro from?

Comment: @Dogbert Sure, here it is: https://gist.github.com/jbernardo95/7f1b6fc604f485af1a237a28ffc5669e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `every` in your [`TestScheduler`](https://gist.github.com/jbernardo95/7f1b6fc604f485af1a237a28ffc5669e#file-scheduler-ex-L4) during compilation stage.

One should either put all the schedule initialization code inside a function, that would be called explicitly *during run stage*, or simply
introduce a new `GenServer`, add it to supervised list (to make Elixir to run it automatically on app start,) and perform this `every` initialization in it’s `start_link` (or any other function that would be called later explicitly):

```
defmodule Test.Scheduler do
  use GenServer
  use Cronex.Scheduler

  def start_link ... do
    every :minute do
      IO.puts "every minute job"
    end

    every :minute do
      IO.puts "every minute job 2"
    end
  end
end
```

Another way round (if you want to keep the file above as clean as possible,) would be *to collect data in `every` macro*, and *to spawn all the calls* during run stage.

---

To become more familiar with stages, put the following code into `/tmp/test.ex`:

```
defmodule A do
  IO.puts "Here “every” macro was called: compilation"

  def a do
    IO.puts "Is not called during compilation stage"
  end
end
IO.puts "=== compilation finished ==="
A.a
```

And issue `elixir /tmp/test.ex`:

```
Here “every” macro was called: compilation
=== compilation finished ===
Is not called during compilation stage
```

Comment: That is exactly the problem, thanks for the explanation !

Comment: I guess I didn't understand completely how compilation stages work.
Everything is run during compilation stage, except the code inside def calls am I right ?

Comment: Welcome. Whether you came from ruby, you might find the similarity: everything on the top level (e.g. DSL inside class declaration) is executed on parsing stage, and functions are just compiled. `def blah do IO.puts end` is compiled, while `IO.puts` is executed directly (in fact, it is being compiled as well, but the compilation of it results in it’s execution.) I hope I just didn’t make everything even more entangled.

Comment: No at all, you made everything make sense to me again, thanks one more time.

Comment: `def` is a macro in Elixir as well and _it is being executed on compilation stage_. The result of execution of `def` is the _“prepared code”_ (AST.) One might as well write on the top level `@fun fn -> IO.puts end`, it will be compiled to make `@fun` _ready to be executed_.

Comment: Hum I see, do you know where I can read a bit more about this ?
Is def the only macro that returns "prepared code" ?

Comment: I would recommend [“Metaprogramming Elixir” by Chris McCord](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24791466-metaprogramming-elixir), but in general there is no rocket science. There is no distinction between macros “returning prepared code” and others, I used this term to express the meaning. Look: `fn e -> fn ee -> ee end end`: this function returns another function, that in turn returns the value. When the macro returns a function, it’s execution is deferred until an explicit call. That’s it, no magic. Play with `quote` to see what is returned.

Comment: Also, the source code is always a good source: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.3.4/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3209

Comment: I read the first chapter of  Metaprogramming Elixir already, I guess I will have to finish it, thanks !